# How to set different colors for intervals on LineChart with iOS charts?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

Related to this question: [How to set different colors for intervals on LineChart at ios charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774576/how-to-set-different-colors-for-intervals-on-linechart-at-ios-charts)

I m using Charts Library (swift) and i need to add a specific color as background color for each interval in line chart like heartrate zones (see image). Any one has an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The library doesn`t have methods for that feature ,so you should create it by yourself.I will give you a simple sample.

First ,create a sub class of YAxisRenderer.

Secondly , copy all codes of "renderGridLines" method from "YAxisRenderer" to your sub class ,so you create a override method of "renderGridLines".

Then, put these codes below the line `let positions = transformedPositions()`

```
let viewPortHandler = self.viewPortHandler
var width =  viewPortHandler.contentBottom -viewPortHandler.contentTop
if positions.count > 1
{
    width = fabs(positions[0] -  positions[1])
}
```

Finally, insert these code after the line `drawGridLine(context: context, position: positions[i])`

```
    context.setStrokeColor(yourColor[i])
    context.setLineWidth(width)
    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: viewPortHandler.contentLeft, y: position.y))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewPortHandler.contentRight, y: position.y))
    context.strokePath()
```

Of course these codes are uncompleted.You should add a property for your sub class in order to store your background colors too.

Comment: I will give it a try today!

Comment: A month later haha sorry! But the method fbs doesn't work? And on which property I need to use this object?

Comment: @AbusiveVids My fault,it is fabs().

Comment: @AbusiveVids  which property I need to use this object? < I mean you should add a property(In my example, it is yourColor[] ) to the class (not object) , in order to hold your background colors, there is no property to use.But because it is depends on grid lines' visibility , you should set your Y Axis like this :   leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true

Comment: Okay I get it. But the colors are depending on the y value of the graph. Is it possible to depends the colors on the values on the Yxis?

Comment: @AbusiveVids I think you don't have a right axis,so I don't know what is the different between "y value of the graph" and "the values on the Yxis".Did you mean you want the background colors can scroll with or not with Y axis?

Comment: If I use your code with my piece of color code than is the output this:
http://imgur.com/a/TOqE5

But the hole graph must be gray because the runner is in the low heartrate zone. It is updating live by a real time heart rate monitor.

Comment: @AbusiveVids OK,I still not get it but I think you are talking about zoom in/out right? If you zoom your graph in/out, the intervals are changed, so background color blocks' size changed too.Yes the solution is not fit for zoom,I will update it later.

Comment: There are five heart rate zones:  50-100 (gray), 100-130 bpm (blue), 130-150 bpm (green), 150-170 (yellow), and 170+ (red). In my example (screenshot in the comments) is only the first heart rate zone visible zo the hole graph must be gray and that is not working. What you see about zooming is also true. If I zoom the background is white again.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your code because if the position is 0,80 and it needs to be blue, it is drawing a blue background at positon 0,70 or something. Don't know why but its gonna wrong.

Comment: And the background colors are not drawing in the right order